# Uncaught TypeError: this.state.imgData.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, laravel

Here id my Data file for image

```
imageData = [
        {
            id: 1,
            imgName: "Apple",
            imgFile: "apple.jpg",
            imgQuestion: "Which fruit is this",
            imgAnswer: "This is an Apple"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            imgName: "Orange",
            imgFile: "orange.jpg",
            imgQuestion: "What is the color of Orange",
            imgAnswer: "The color of orange os orange"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            imgName: "Mango",
            imgFile: "mango.jpg",
            imgQuestion: "Do you like Mangoes",
            imgAnswer: "Yes I like Mangoes"
        }
    ]
```

I don't know why my code is showing error message in browser console:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.state.imgData.map is not a function

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Jokes from './../components/Jokes';
import Data from './../data';

export default class Index extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            imgData: Data
        }
    }

    render() {
        const imgDataItem = this.state.imgData.map(item => {
            <Jokes  data={{key: this.item.id}}
                    data={{
                        img: this.item.imgName,
                        imgFileName: this.item.imgFile,
                        question: this.item.imgQuestion,
                        answer: this.item.imgAnswer
                    }}
            />
        })

        return (
            {imgDataItem}            
        )
    }
}
```

I am new to react and please get me the solution where I am getting wrong

Comment: map can only be applied to array... imgData is not an array

Comment: please show what is in `'./../data'`

Comment: i have send the `./../data` file.. please solve my problem..

Comment: What are you exporting? Do console.log(Data) in constructer to see if you are getting whats you expect i.e. an array

Comment: ok ill try to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Try [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with assignment by default value for `imgData`

```
 render() {
    const {imgData = []} = this.state; 
    const imgDataItem = imgData.map(item => {
        <Jokes  data={{key: this.item.id}}
                data={{
                    img: this.item.imgName,
                    imgFileName: this.item.imgFile,
                    question: this.item.imgQuestion,
                    answer: this.item.imgAnswer
                }}
        />
    })

    return (
        {imgDataItem}            
    )
}
```